# how get parent size in child view in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I cannot understand how can I send parent view's sizes to child component of this. In renderPager() I want calculate some parameters that depend on parent view size. I know that we can do it through onLayout(). problem is that onLayout will be called only after building all of childs (I see it by the console log). how can I do it?

```
 onPageLayout = (event) => {
    const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    console.log("ON LAYOUT");
  }; 

render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.root}
        onLayout={this.onPageLayout}
      >
        {this.renderPager()}
      </View>
    );
  }

renderPager = () => {
   // how can get root view's size here
    return (
      <IndicatorViewPager
        ref={(ref) => (this.viewPager = ref)}
        scrollEnabled={!this.state.isDragging}
        onPageScroll={this.onPageScroll}
        style={styles.pageRoot}
      >
        {this.renderPages()}
      </IndicatorViewPager>
    );
  };
```

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can maybe pass the data as props, and take the prop data from the store. You are right in that `onLayout` will only be triggered after everything is rendered, but that simply means that you have to pass the props with a null value on the first render. For instance:

```
onPageLayout = (event) => {
    const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    console.log("ON LAYOUT");
    this.setState({width, height})
  }; 

render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.root}
        onLayout={this.onPageLayout}
      >
        {this.renderPager(this.state.width, this.state.height)}
      </View>
    );
  }

renderPager = (width, height) => {
   // Do something if width or height are null
   // how can get root view's size here
    return (
      <IndicatorViewPager
        ref={(ref) => (this.viewPager = ref)}
        scrollEnabled={!this.state.isDragging}
        onPageScroll={this.onPageScroll}
        style={styles.pageRoot}
      >
        {this.renderPages()}
      </IndicatorViewPager>
    );
  };
```

Also you could use the `measure` function of the parent, but I think that might be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: With this method it seems that onLayout is getting stuck in an endless loop because we are setting state within the render function.

Comment: @kojow7 You might be right, thanks for flagging it. If this is the case, a solution is to save width and height as attributes instead of as part of the state, or to oveload `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/2bf6fa1e58d30c5977810b737c6173c0

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, ViewProps} from 'react-native';

interface ContainerWithDimensionsProps extends ViewProps {
  children: ({
    width,
    height,
  }: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  }) => React.ReactNode;
}

export const ContainerWithDimensions: React.FC<
  ContainerWithDimensionsProps
> = ({children, ...props}: ContainerWithDimensionsProps) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={event =>
        setDimensions({
          width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width,
          height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height,
        })
      }
      {...props}>
      {children(dimensions)}
    </View>
  );
};

// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
// usage

// <ContainerWithDimensions>
//   {({width, height}) => {
//     console.log('width', width);
//     console.log('height', height);
//     return <View />;
//   }}
// </ContainerWithDimensions>;
```